# Plural noun after an “and” conjunction

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions

I work for two campuses in the same company. If I were to write an email, what should my signature be?

John Doe
Assistant Clerk
***A and B campus***
Phone:12345678

Or

**A and B campuses**

Comment: Do you need to say "campus" at all? *John Doe, Assistant Clerk, Cupertino and Austin...*

Comment: Your first variant is incorrect. It _would_ be correct if you were based at a single campus named say 'Currier and Ives [Campus]'.